# how to get data from firebase realtime database without refresh page by laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how to get data from realtime  firebase  database  when send request by  mobile application to database without refresh page by laravel

```
    public function getdata(){
$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/trackingmap-eb9e4-firebase-adminsdk-q7to8-6c004a5629.json');

  $firebase = (new Factory())
         ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
         ->create();
         $db = $firebase->getDatabase();
         $reference = $db->getReference('users');
         //  $value = $reference->getValue();
        // or
          $snapshot = $reference->getSnapshot();
        //   $value=$snapshot->get('01');//Get /test/01 as an array
          $value=$snapshot->getvalue();

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by „refresh“? I would recommend using a client SDK to access the Firebase Platform from a Client application.

Comment: I need to get data automatic from realtime database , it  the data send from mobile to realtime database , This data is the points the user moves in a tracking app ,I send it points to realtime database ,Now I need  get last points to calculate the distance  then When a certain distance remains, I send a notification from larvel web application that containing the distance

Comment: how to do it by laravel , Any example on it? thanx.

Comment: It would be more "native" to use Firebase Cloud Functions for that, and you wouldn't need a backend application for that. The Firebase SDK for PHP is not capable of listening to events like "onCreated" on the Realtime Database - it would be a big overhead to implement this on a PHP backend server, so I wouldn't recommend it :/. But if you need to do it, https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io should get you started with examples.